# Remover espaços em branco entre valores de um array

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho um *array* que esta retornando os seguintes dados como mostra no exemplo a seguir:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052442VILA FELIZ (PLANALTINA)                                                      00000000                                                                        CONJUNTO                                                                                                   00742207A                                                                       CJ A                                                                    73366203NS                                                                                                        

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052442VILA FELIZ (PLANALTINA)                                                      00000000                                                                        CONJUNTO                                                                                                   00742207A                                                                       CJ A                                                                    73366203NS                                                                                                        

            [1] => DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052443RESIDENCIAL FLAMBOYANT (PLANALTINA)                                          00000000                                                                        CONJUNTO                                                                                                   00742211A                                                                       CJ A                                                                    73366243NS     

        )
)
```

Como faço para remover espaços em branco entre os valores?

Comment: Tem varias formas de fazer isso Humberto, mas tratar essa saída na origem pode ser melhor. Explique melhor de onde vem esse array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiser remover todos os espaços use o `str_replace()`, [veja no manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php).

```
 str_replace(' ', '', 'DDF      00001778BRASILIA');
 // Resultado: DDF00001778BRASILIA
```

*Se quiser remover apenas os espaços repetidos, mas mantendo um deles, use o preg_replace.*

```
 preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', 'DDF      00001778BRASILIA');
 // Resultado: DDF 00001778BRASILIA
```

Isso irá remover todos os espaços em branco entre os valores, como deseja.

Um exemplo de uso para o seu caso, em especifico:

```
<?php


$arrays = array(
    array(
            'DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052442VILA FELIZ (PLANALTINA)                                                      00000000                                                                        CONJUNTO                                                                                                   00742207A                                                                       CJ A                                                                    73366203NS'                                                                                                        

        ),

    array
        (
            'DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052442VILA FELIZ (PLANALTINA)                                                      00000000                                                                        CONJUNTO                                                                                                   00742207A                                                                       CJ A                                                                    73366203NS',                                                                                                        

            'DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052443RESIDENCIAL FLAMBOYANT (PLANALTINA)                                          00000000                                                                        CONJUNTO                                                                                                   00742211A                                                                       CJ A                                                                    73366243NS'     

        )
);

$idPrincipal = 0;
$idSecundario = 0;

foreach($arrays as $array){



   foreach($array as $a){
       # Remover todos:
       $arrays[$idPrincipal][$idSecundario] = str_replace(' ', '', $a);
       // OU
       # Remover repetidos, mantendo um:
       $arrays[$idPrincipal][$idSecundario] = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $a);

       $idSecundario++;
   }

   $idPrincipal++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma melhor de fazer isso a meu ver é usar a função array_map. Assim:

```
function removeEspacos($str) {
    return str_replace(' ', '', $str);
}; 

$narr = array();
foreach($arr as $a)
    $narr[] = array_map('removeEspacos', $a);
```

Fiz um exemplo funcional no Ideone: http://ideone.com/zHl3Ht

Comment: Obrigado pessoal agradeço muito ajuda de vocês e me serviu cada exemplo aqui referido..

Comment: Se as respostas foram úteis por favor dê um voto positivo nelas e aceite a que achar mais útil.  Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o `str_replace`, como já sugerido. Você não especificou, mas tenho quase certeza que você quer apenas eliminar os espaços extras.

Então, sugiro que faça dessa forma:

```
  $array = [
    ["DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052442VILA FELIZ (PLANALTINA) "],
    ["DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052442VILA FELIZ (PLANALTINA)",
     "DDF      00001778BRASILIA                                                                     00052443RESIDENCIAL FLAMBOYANT (PLANALTINA)"
    ]
  ];


for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
      for ($j=0;$j<count($array[$i]);$j++){
          $array[$i][$j] = trim(preg_replace('/ +/',' ', $array[$i][$j]));
      }
  }


  print_r($array);
```